# Kohana 3.2.0, logging works incorrectly - INFO as DEBUG and ALERT as CRITICAL

Tags: debugging, kohana

I use Kohana 3.2.0 and while using logging in my code as shown below the output written to the log file is not as expected. The content is written correctly but the logging 'level' is wrong. This works fine for all the logging levels except for 'INFO' and 'ALERT'. For INFO it writes as DEBUG and for ALERT it writes as CRITICAL.

In the controller -

> Log::instance()->add(Log::INFO, 'The match found is '.$matches[0]);

In the log file -

> 2013-03-25 11:48:26 --- DEBUG: The match found is fruits

The \system\classes\kohana\log.php has below values.

```
    >const EMERGENCY = LOG_EMERG;    // 0
>const ALERT     = LOG_ALERT;    // 1
>const CRITICAL  = LOG_CRIT;     // 2
>const ERROR     = LOG_ERR;      // 3
>const WARNING   = LOG_WARNING;  // 4
>const NOTICE    = LOG_NOTICE;   // 5
>const INFO      = LOG_INFO;     // 6
>const DEBUG     = LOG_DEBUG;    // 7
>const STRACE    = 8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely seeing this behaviour on Windows. This is because Windows has less log levels - see [PHP bug #18090](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18090).

The log levels on Windows are mapped as following:

```
LOG_EMERG   => critical
LOG_ALERT   => critical
LOG_CRIT    => critical
LOG_ERR     => error
LOG_WARNING => warning
LOG_NOTICE  => debug
LOG_INFO    => debug
LOG_DEBUG   => debug
```

Comment: Thanks Mike that answers my question.